# How to know who Liked my pages on Facebook via my website

Tags: facebook-graph

I'm using Facebook Social Plugin on my website. But I don't know who came to my website and liked my individual pages. If you take a look at my pages, you can see a person has liked it but who?

Comment: Do you have google analytics setup? Might be too late to do this but you can track clicks henceforth.

Comment: I got it setup but then I still want to know who liked my website so I can contact them individually. :) Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: I think you're better off adding a contact form on that particular page and working toward high conversion rates. What you're suggesting isn't an optimal approach -- You can just make your life easier.

Comment: Oh sorry Chris J. Lee, normally I will receive update in my email but this time, I haven't received so I didn't know you commented on this. :) thanks for your advise! I'm also thinking like you suggested! :D

Answer (score 2):

Unless something's changed since [this follow-up post](http://blog.facebook.com/blog.php?post=384733792130) to their social graph announcement, you can't. Except for people who are your FB friends. There's a lot of information, but you're primarily interested in these sections:

- What information about me does Facebook share with the websites hosting social plugins?, and
- Will people beyond my friends see what I like or recommend?

Comment: what a pity! If we can see that information, it would be very advantageous because we can contact our customers directly. :) Thanks for your effort! Kind Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546320/how-to-list-facebook-users-who-like-a-page-or-interest) [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018849/facebook-api-get-fans-of-people-who-like-a-page) ways to do this. It's just not as simple as simply embedding the Facebook social plugin.

You can use the social graph API to fetch the last 500 fans to like a page.

You can also gradually scrape the data by repeatedly refreshing the social plugin and recording unique user IDs.

You can also [use Facebook's JavaScript SDK to subscribe to the `edge.create` event](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).

And you can also [use FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/) from a Facebook app to [check if a user likes a URL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/), if the user has given your app permission to view their likes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using my website, I created a Facebook page. Any "like" on your website will be posted to your Facebook page.